# How to convert checkboxes to a comma delimited string

Tags: angular, typescript

I am using this Angular code to generate checkboxes:

```
<div class="col-2" *ngFor="let item of selectedUsers; let idx=index">
  <input name="SelectedEntity" value="{{item}}" type="checkbox">
</div>
```

I want to convert the selected checkboxes into a comma-delimited string like this:

```
selectedEntity:"users1, users2"
```

How can I do this?

Answer (score 1):

You have the array of selectedUsers already, and the SelectedEntity will return an array of booleans.  Just loop through selectedUsers and if the checkbox array is TRUE then push the element at that index into a new array.  Once that's done just use the join Javascript function to delimit the list.

```
let selectedArray = [];
for (let index=0; index < selectedUsers.length; index++) {
  if(SelectedEntity[index] === true) {
    selectedArray.push(selectedUsers[index]);
  }
}
selectedArray.join(", ");
```

Comment: on click of  search, I will get list of Selectedusers in object  ["User1", "User2", "User3"].  So I'm  looping in checkbox for displaying has shown above. After display multiple checkbox. Based on selection i need to parse in a selectedEntity:"User1,User3"

Answer (score 0):

Html:

```
<div class="col-2" *ngFor="let item of selectedUsers; let idx=index">
     <input [(ngModel)]="item.isSelected" type="checkbox">
</div>
```

Component:

```
var result = "";
for(let i = 0; i < this.selectedUsers.length; i++) {
    if(this.selectedUsers[i].isSelected) {
         if(result != "") {
             result += ", ";
         }
         result += this.selectedUsers[i].name;
    }
}
console.log("selectedEntity:\"" + result + "\"");
```

If you don't want to make a list of objects out of selectedUsers, you can always use a different list:

Html:

```
<div class="col-2" *ngFor="let item of selectedUsers; let idx=index">
     <input [(ngModel)]="selection[idx]" type="checkbox">
</div>
```

Component:

```
var result = "";
for(let i = 0; i < this.selection.length; i++) {
    if(this.selection[i]) {
         if(result != "") {
             result += ", ";
         }
         result += this.selectedUsers[i];
    }
}
console.log("selectedEntity:\"" + result + "\"");
```

Though I wouldn't recommend that approach as the selection is tied to the item and should be represented has such in the model.